# QDirIterator (Windows) should be case insensitive but not

Tags: c++, qt

I have a directory with 2 files:
Test1.txt and test2.txt

This code should list me the two files:

```
QDirIterator *it;
QStringList nameFilters;
nameFilters << "t*.txt";
QString path = "C:/temp/test";
qDebug() << "nameFilters" << nameFilters;
it = new QDirIterator(path, nameFilters, QDir::NoFilter, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (it->hasNext()) {
    QString filename = it->next();
    qDebug() << "filename" << filename;
}
```

but the output is :

```
nameFilters ("t*.txt") 
filename "C:/temp/test/test2.txt"
```

Note that this code works well:

```
QDir dir(path);
qDebug() << dir.entryList(nameFilters, QDir::NoFilter);
```

Outputs for QDir :

```
entryList ("Test1.txt", "test2.txt")
```

Comment: Interesting, its probably because Qt handles the filtering in Qt code

Comment: I think you skip the first entry in your code. What if you call `qDebug() << "filename" << filename;` before you advance to the next entry with `it->next()`?

Comment: Hmm the code: [https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qdiriterator.cpp.html#181](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qdiriterator.cpp.html#181) looks like there is a case insensitive way and the default is case insensitive.

Comment: @vahancho the example is correct, `QDirIterator` starts before the first entry [(At least thats what the docs say)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html#details)

Comment: NTFS IS case-sentive filesystem. How API works depends on what flag is passed. It's "POSIX" API in past on Windows was case-insensitive to be  compatible with FAT.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not a bug in the core library but a subtle implementation quirk (?) in the `Filter` enum of Qt's `QDir` class.

Usually you will set the `QDir::Filter` parameter in your `QDirIterator` constructor to `QDir::NoFilter`. This enum member is defined to be negative one (all bits set):

```
NoFilter = -1
```

Among these bits, there's one called `CaseSensitive`:

```
CaseSensitive = 0x800,
```

This bit gets set when using `QDir::NoFilter`, but it should be cleared for Windows programs like yours.

I get the desired results by using this kind of code. omitting the `QDir::NoFilter` flags altogether:

```
#if _WIN32
    QDir::Filter filter = (QDir::Filter)((int)QDir::Filter::Files | (int)QDir::Filter::Readable);
#else
    QDir::Filter filter = QDir::Filter::NoFilter;
#endif
    QDirIterator it(path, nameFilters, filter, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a Qt core I/O bug. Ticket https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-88227 created.